# Function operators and function wrapping in R

Tags: r, functional-programming, dplyr

Hadley's "[Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Function-operators.html)" gives us a brief insight into functional programming and possible applications of "function operators" . However, my concern is that I either do not fully understand how these simplify the code, or unwillingly follow some bad practices by using other solutions.

Instead of creating operators that expect an input to be a function, I create a wrapper, that takes an expression as its argument, and returns a complete output (instead of a function, that still needs to be called). See example:

```
# function operator
delay_by <- function(delay, f) {
  function(...) {
    Sys.sleep(delay)
    f(...)
  }
}

# simple wrapper
delay_by2 <- function(expr, delay) { 
  Sys.sleep(delay)
  eval(expr)
}

delay_by(1, sqrt)(2)
delay_by2(sqrt(2), 1)

operator <- delay_by(1, sqrt)
wrapper <- function(x) delay_by2(sqrt(x), 1)

operator(2)
wrapper(2)
```

This approach still allows for feeding into functionals (sapply etc.) and applying memoisation. In addition, this supports piping with `%>%`.

```
lapply(1:10, function(x) sqrt(x) %>% delay_by2(1))
```

The potential drawback of this solution is that it does not create persistent execution environments to store variables maintaining function's state, but these may be created explicitly with `<<- new.env()`.

Is there any reason why I should consider my approach inferior? I am trying to avoid an unnecessary nesting.

Comment: The eval approach does not allow precomopilation. It could conceivably be used in a code injection scenario too. But those are minor concerns for non production code.

Comment: Regarding the safety issues - am I correct saying, that there's no benefit over `eval()`, if the function operator does not perform the check, if a supplied function is white-listed?

Comment: Actually, if you are using `eval(,,)`, and not `eval(parse(..))`, maybe my objections do not hold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- One important software engineering aspect is that functions are easy 
  to test and package, expressions not so much. So if you use a 
  function approach you can write unit tests, and put it in a package. 
  With the eval approach you are limited to your own REPL testing. Obviously we  should all be doing "Test Driven Development", at least    on our production  code, and nothing should go out the door
  without a    set of unit tests that cover as much of the code as
  economically    possible. This makes life much easier for people
  (including you) who    might need to make changes someday.
- Also note that there may be compiler optimizations that can be    done function-wide, but not on expressions. That would be true
  in    other languages, but I don't know enough about how R's compiler
  works    to say anything about that.
- Another point that occurs to me is that the eval route is not really    scalable, i.e. only practical for expressions up to a
  certain    complexity. Using functions on the other hand allows your
  logic to    grow to any practical size.
- Finally, `eval` as a construct is a very powerful one, but one that can get you in trouble, kind of like using a high-powered laser to
  cut paper. Since it is often easy to implement, it exists in many
  languages, and there are a lot of articles on the net about why it is dangerous - you should look at them. So like that high-powered laser, you shouldn't really get
  in the habit of using it except where it is necessary.